# Loop over grouped pandas df and export individual plots

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

[The documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#iterating-through-groups) seems a little sparse, as to how every element works, so here goes:

I have a bunch of files that I would like to iterate over and export a plot, for every single file.

```
df_all.head()
```

Returns

```
    Dem-Dexc    Aem-Dexc    Aem-Aexc    S       E     fit     frame filename
0   18150.0595  18548.2451  15263.7451  0.7063  0.5054  0.879   1.0 Traces_exp22_tif_pair16.txt
1   596.9286    7161.7353   1652.8922   0.8244  0.9231  0.879   2.0 Traces_exp22_tif_pair16.txt
2   93.2976     3112.3725   2632.6667   0.5491  0.9709  0.879   3.0 Traces_exp22_tif_pair16.txt
3   1481.1310   4365.4902   769.3333    0.8837  0.7467  0.879   4.0 Traces_exp22_tif_pair16.txt
4   583.1786    6192.6373   1225.5392   0.8468  0.9139  0.879   5.0 Traces_exp22_tif_pair16.txt
```

And now I would like to group and iterate:

```
for group in df_all.groupby("filename"):
    plot = sns.regplot(data = group, x = "Dem-Dexc", y = "frame")
```

But I get `TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str`. Why do I get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need change:

```
for group in df_all.groupby("filename")
```

to:

```
for i, group in df_all.groupby("filename"):
    plot = sns.regplot(data = group, x = "Dem-Dexc", y = "frame")
```

for unpack `tuples`.

Or select second value of tuple by `[1]`:

```
for group in df_all.groupby("filename"):
    plot = sns.regplot(data = group[1], x = "Dem-Dexc", y = "frame")
```

You can check `tuple` output by:

```
for group in df_all.groupby("filename"):
    print (group)

('Traces_exp22_tif_pair16.txt',      Dem-Dexc    Aem-Dexc    Aem-Aexc       S       E    fit  frame  \
0  18150.0595  18548.2451  15263.7451  0.7063  0.5054  0.879    1.0   
1    596.9286   7161.7353   1652.8922  0.8244  0.9231  0.879    2.0   
2     93.2976   3112.3725   2632.6667  0.5491  0.9709  0.879    3.0   
3   1481.1310   4365.4902    769.3333  0.8837  0.7467  0.879    4.0   
4    583.1786   6192.6373   1225.5392  0.8468  0.9139  0.879    5.0   

                      filename  
0  Traces_exp22_tif_pair16.txt  
1  Traces_exp22_tif_pair16.txt  
2  Traces_exp22_tif_pair16.txt  
3  Traces_exp22_tif_pair16.txt  
4  Traces_exp22_tif_pair16.txt  )
```

vs:

```
for i, group in df_all.groupby("filename"):
    print (group)

     Dem-Dexc    Aem-Dexc    Aem-Aexc       S       E    fit  frame  \
0  18150.0595  18548.2451  15263.7451  0.7063  0.5054  0.879    1.0   
1    596.9286   7161.7353   1652.8922  0.8244  0.9231  0.879    2.0   
2     93.2976   3112.3725   2632.6667  0.5491  0.9709  0.879    3.0   
3   1481.1310   4365.4902    769.3333  0.8837  0.7467  0.879    4.0   
4    583.1786   6192.6373   1225.5392  0.8468  0.9139  0.879    5.0   

                      filename  
0  Traces_exp22_tif_pair16.txt  
1  Traces_exp22_tif_pair16.txt  
2  Traces_exp22_tif_pair16.txt  
3  Traces_exp22_tif_pair16.txt  
4  Traces_exp22_tif_pair16.txt
```

If want save output to pictures `png`:

```
for i, group in df_all.groupby("filename"):
    plot = sns.regplot(data = group, x = "Dem-Dexc", y = "frame")
    fig = plot.get_figure()
    fig.savefig("{}.png".format(i.split('.')[0]))
```

Comment: Now I'm getting `TypeError: Could not convert 24540.50005151.2500633.5000550.0000-1204.50002094.0000-1045.2500742.750052.75003610.75009719 (...) to numeric.`

It seems like it has some problems parsing the dataframe, even though printing looks perfectly fine. What gives?

Comment: I think you need `df['Dem-Dexc'] = df['Dem-Dexc'].astype(float)`, because in column are strings.

Comment: You're right. That's an error on my side. Seems some of my dataframe was put together as strings in the initial import. Thanks!